# Matrix automation in sympy and conversion to numpy

Tags: numpy, loops, for-loop, matrix, sympy

So, I am trying to create a [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWy3m.png) where the elements are answers to definite integrals. The elements in this matrix (ψ_1, ψ_2, ψ_3, ψ_4). You can see in the matrix that the subscripts of ψ here are just the index of the matrix element. I don't know if you can create matrix without typing it explicitly (like using a for loop or something). These definite integrals are going to be created in sympy which would then be converted to an array in numpy.

I can do this in numpy easily but integrals are not going to be accurate in numpy, thus I want sympy. How do I get to do this in sympy?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your are asking. Let's say (ψ_1, ψ_2, ψ_3, ψ_4) are symbolic expressions. For convenience, I'm going to represent them as symbols :

```py
P = Matrix(symbols("psi1:5"))
P_conj = conjugate(P)
z, V = symbols("z, V")
M = (P_conj * P.T * z).applyfunc(lambda t: Integral(t, V))
M
```

If you are interested in the results, you should replace `Integral` with `integrate`.